# Call a function by name from a variable?

Tags: javascript

Ruby has a `.method()` call where you can dynamically cal a method from an object.  So if @object has @object.foo() and @object.bar() methods you could call `@object.method(‘foo’).call` etc.

In JavaScript let’s say you have two functions defined the same `foo() {}` and `bar() {}` and I have a variable set like `var type = ‘foo’`.  Can you somehow call those functions dynamically from that variable?

Still learning JS so this may be a trivial question but I can’t seem find a quick answer.

Comment: Object methods are just properties, so you use `object[type]()`

Comment: The object example was ruby not JS.

Comment: The 'answered' question doesn't answer MY question at all.  I ended up with this:

https://jsfiddle.net/jasper502/h87urnL2/3/